# Struts2 Annotaion Based Action configuration

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, annotations, struts2-convention-plugin

What is the cause of this exception, whats wrong with it? Thanks in Advance.

```
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'ActionAnnotation' in namespace: '/'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
```

**HTML:**

```
        <s:form action="ActionAnnotation" >            
            <s:submit  value="ActionAnnotation"/>
        </s:form>
```

**Action :**

```
@ResultPath(value="/")
@Result(name="success",location="differenactions.jsp")
public class ActionAnnotationAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String message;


    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("ActionAnnotation : Hello How are you execute() method got called.....");
        setMessage("ActionAnnotation : Hello How are you");
        return "success";

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following annotations needed

```
@Namespace("/")
@Action(value="ActionAnnotation", results=@Result(name="success", location="/differenactions.jsp"))
public class ActionAnnotationAction extends ActionSupport{
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Default namespace is ""(emptystring) then why we need add "/" ?

Comment: and still am getting the same exception.

Comment: The path is evaluated by adding namespace to action name and this should be absolute, if Struts didn't find a namespace from the action config it's trying to fallback to default namespace but default namespace doesn't have slash and it could be a problem.

Comment: The @ParentPackage annotation also required if you are not configured it globally.

Comment: am not adding any xml configuration , then I have to add parent package or what ? please let me know.Thanks for reply.

Comment: You don't have to, until you don't need to define custom configuration. have you added convention plugin to the classpath?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43440/discussion-between-sunleo-and-roman-c)